# website responsive using media-queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I build a website using bootstrap & its work properly in every mobile view, but in "320px" resolution when i rotted my mobile view the responsive view is not work properly, please give some advice how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

use media-queries and set max-width to 320px

```
@media (max-width: 320px){
 //write css code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down)**

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}
```

**Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}
```

**Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

**Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}
```

**Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```